# Rails 3 => :has_many Xs, through => Y, Z

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

i'm trying to do something like

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many    :links, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to  :activity
  belongs_to  :facility
  has_many    :infos, :through => :activity
  has_many    :infos, :through => :facility

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :infos

end
```

But this results in `has_many    :infos, :through => :facility`, while `has_many    :infos, :through => :activity` is ignored.

How can i express this in a correct syntax?

**EDIT:**

If i implement Vlad's method and then use

@events = Event.all(:include => [:facility_infos, :activity_infos], :conditions => ["infos.language_id = ?", 2], :order => :time)

i get the `:activity_infos` for language_id == 2, but unfortunately i get the `:facility_infos` for all the languages! 
How to solve this?

**EDIT 2:**

Here's the output you requested:

SELECT "events"."id" AS t0_r0, "events"."time" AS t0_r1, "events"."everyday" AS t0_r2, "events"."activity_id" AS t0_r3, "events"."created_at" AS t0_r4, "events"."updated_at" AS t0_r5, "events"."facility_id" AS t0_r6, "events"."home" AS t0_r7, "infos"."id" AS t1_r0, "infos"."title" AS t1_r1, "infos"."description" AS t1_r2, "infos"."location" AS t1_r3, "infos"."language_id" AS t1_r4, "infos"."created_at" AS t1_r5, "infos"."updated_at" AS t1_r6, "infos"."activity_id" AS t1_r7, "infos"."facility_id" AS t1_r8, "infos"."service_id" AS t1_r9, "activity_infos_events"."id" AS t2_r0, "activity_infos_events"."title" AS t2_r1, "activity_infos_events"."description" AS t2_r2, "activity_infos_events"."location" AS t2_r3, "activity_infos_events"."language_id" AS t2_r4, "activity_infos_events"."created_at" AS t2_r5, "activity_infos_events"."updated_at" AS t2_r6, "activity_infos_events"."activity_id" AS t2_r7, "activity_infos_events"."facility_id" AS t2_r8, "activity_infos_events"."service_id" AS t2_r9 FROM "events" LEFT OUTER JOIN "facilities" ON "events"."facility_id" = "facilities"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "infos" ON "infos"."facility_id" = "facilities"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "activities" ON "events"."activity_id" = "activities"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "infos" "activity_infos_events" ON "activity_infos_events"."activity_id" = "activities"."id" WHERE (infos.language_id = 2) ORDER BY time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701175/access-has-many-relation-in-two-diferent-ways-activerecord-rails

Comment: updated my post. This should return an sql query so we could check what's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you could do as follows:

```
has_many :activity_infos, :through => :activity, :source => :infos, :class_name => "Info"
has_many :facility_infos, :thorough => :facility, :source => :infos, :class_name => "Info"


def infos
  activity_infos + facility_infos
end
```

UPDATE:

please show an output of below:

```
Event.includes([:facility_infos, :activity_infos]).where(['infos.language_id = ?', 2]).to_sql
```

UPDATE 2 :

looks like

```
Event.includes([:facility_infos, :activity_infos]).where(['infos.language_id = ? AND activity_infos_events.language_id = ?', 2, 2])
```

should return what you expect?

Comment: Hi Vlad, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately i'm still having some problems... please can you see my edit? THANKS!

Comment: Great, this is it! Oh, and thanks for the ".to_sql" trick, this will be useful!